# Is it possible to update an assembly version at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom attribute which I set in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`. I want to update this custom attribute at runtime. Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The metadata in an assembly is fixed and not mutatable at runtime.